# how to display thousands of records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatable

I have a table called clientes, this table has around 15536 records, which makes data loading extremely slow. How can I optimize the log load to improve the process?

this is my index view

```
<h1>Clientes</h1>
<style>
.container {
}

</style>




  <table id="clientes" class="display"><!--el id clientes es de datatables referenciado en clientes.coffe y display class es una clase de datatables-->
  <thead>

    <tr><!--active es para sombrear la fila-->
      <th>Clave</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Nombre Corto</th>
      <th>Dirección</th>
      <th>Colonia</th>
      <th>Credito</th>
      <th>DiasCredito</th>
      <th>LimiteCredito</th>
      <th>Saldo</th>
      <th>Ruta</th>
      <th>Promociones</th>
      <th>Acción</th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody id="container_clientes">
      <%= render @clientes %><!--carga todos los clientes-->
</tbody>
```

my partial cliente.html.erb

```
<tr id="cliente_<%= cliente.id %>">
  <td><%=cliente.IdCli%>

</td>
  <td><%=cliente.Nombre%></td>
  <td><%=cliente.NombreCorto%></td>
  <td><%=cliente.Direccion%></td>
  <td><%=cliente.Colonia%></td>
  <td>
    <% if cliente.Credito == true%>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled="true" checked="true">
    <%else%>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled="true" >
    <%end%>
  </td>
  <td><%=cliente.DiasCreedito%></td>
  <td><%=cliente.LimiteCredito%></td>
  <td>
    <% if cliente.detallecob.last != nil%>
        <%=cliente.detallecob.last.Saldo%>
      <%else%>
        <%=cliente.Saldo%>
    <%end%>
  </td>
  <td>
    <% if cliente.relclirutas != nil%>
      <% cliente.relclirutas.each do |varias| %>
        <%=varias.ruta.Ruta%>
      <%end%>
    <%end%>
  </td>
  <td>
    <% if cliente.relclili != nil%>
      <%=cliente.relclili.listapromomast.ListaMaster%>
    <%end%>
  </td>


    <td>
        <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i> Activos'.html_safe, activos_cliente_path(cliente), class:"btn btn-primary btn-xs boton" %>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myupdatecliente_<%= cliente.id %>">
          Editar
        </button>
        <!--Destroy-->
        <% if cliente.Status == true%>
          <%= link_to 'Eliminar', cliente, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs", remote:true %>
        <%else%>
          <%= link_to 'Habilitar', cliente, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-success btn-xs", remote:true %>
        <%end%>
      </td>


<td class="no" >
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Did you do paging for the data or just load at one time?

Comment: It's a simple decision.  On the one hand you can load all your records into the browser at once.  How long it takes to load depends on many things beyond your control, such as the user's computer.  It might be worth the wait.  On the other hand, you can quickly load a few records at a time and make the user select something to see more.  Like all decisions, each option has at least advantage over the other.

Comment: @gaga5lala just load one time, in the datatable

Comment: @DanBracuk Which one would you recommend using the datatable?

Comment: If I were the user, I'd want to see every record.  I can use the browser's find capability to look for something specific.  I don't like extra mouse clicks.  However, I'm not your user.

Comment: You can look up infinite scrolling.

Comment: @RubyRacer infitine scrolling I think it is not used with datatables or is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem for data paging, just take part of data and require more by access next page.

```
Cliente.page(1).per(50)
```

kaminari also do the pagination links for you, just use the helper

```
<%= paginate @cliente %>
```

You can find the usage in [README](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari).

For better UX, you should make the request communicate by API(AJAX), and  use some tech like infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You could offload your fetching. This means, use a slightly more complex approach with javascript and ajax. I will not use a pagination gem in this example.

Modify your controller:

```
def index
    if !params[:page].blank?
        respond_to do |f|
            f.html {}
            f.json { # only for pagination, work around this to make it more complex
                offset = 50*params[:page].to_i
                @clients = Client.offset(offset).limit(50).select("field1, field2") # appended to any other condition you may have
                render :json => @clients.as_json
            }
        end
    else
        @clients = Client.limit(50)
    end
end
```

I will not post more, you can figure it out. On document load, add an ajax fetch event that will:

- Call /clientes?page=2 etc (add an increment counter)
- Do until you get an empty response the following:

  - For each row you get of the json response, append a row to the table, following the partial code

You may do it with a timer or a loop. But this is a way your page will become responsive after loading a first set of rows (in this example 50) and then, while you work, more rows will be fetching.

Comment: thanks for answer. this method works using datatable?

Comment: What is `datatable`? All I see in your question is a table and a render for each row. This should work, as according to your question...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess because I am not a ruby programmer, but, let's look at this:

```
<td>
    <% if cliente.relclirutas != nil%>
      <% cliente.relclirutas.each do |varias| %>
        <%=varias.ruta.Ruta%>
      <%end%>
    <%end%>
  </td>
```

If that means,

```
if cliente.relclirutas is not null or an empty string
loop through it and display each value of varias.ruta.Ruta
```

Then you don't need the if statement.  Simply loop through the null value or empty string.  This might save you a few nanoseconds on each record, of which you have 15,000 plus.